# $f(\frac{x^2}{x+1}) = p(x)$

Tags: contest-math

Does there exist a rational function $f$ and a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ so that:
$$f(\frac{x^2}{x+1}) = p(x)$$

Comment: Polynomials are defined at $x=-1$, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All such functions $f$ must be constant. Here's a proof.

Suppose $f$ and $p$ satisfy the conditions of the problem. We must then have: $$p(-1)=\lim_{x\to-1^+}p(x)=\lim_{x\to-1^+}f\left(\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x).$$ Since $p(x)$ tends to a finite value as $x\to\infty$, $p$ must be a constant polynomial. In particular, $f$ must be constant in the range of $\frac{x^2}{x+1}$, which is an infinite set, implying that $f$ must also be constant. This proves what we wanted. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: URL. What an idea! But as it stands f is not defined at x=-1, hence cannot be a polynomial. Define f at x=-1 to be =  constant pol. =c , then OK.Hope this makes sense:)

Comment: @PeterSzilas You can do pretty much whatever at the point $x=-1$, if we ignore it altogether in the original problem redaction. My solution only really cares about what happens in its neighborhood ;)

Comment: Fine.The problem : one equates a continuos polynomial with a function that is not defined at x=-1. Assuming a continuos extension of f at x=-1, you show that it is impossible unless f=p=constant.